JSON_ARRAYAGG vs JSON_ARRAY
Could you please explain to me the principal differences (if possible with some example) in simple explanation between JSON_ARRAYAGG and JSON_ARRAY
and where these are better to use.

The JSON functions were introduced in Oracle 12, your question is tagged Oracle 10 and Oracle 11 - neither of which supported either of those functions. Additionally, those functions are SQL functions and not PL/SQL.

From Oracle 12, where these functions were introduced:

JSON_ARRAY is a scalar function and combines values within a single row. You can compare it to the addition operator where the equivalent is the + operator.
JSON_ARRAYAGG is an aggregation function and combines multiple rows. You can compare it to the addition operator where the equivalent is the SUM aggregation function to add values across multiple rows.

If you have the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (a, b) AS
SELECT 1, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 6 FROM DUAL;

Then:
SELECT JSON_ARRAY(a, b) AS ab FROM table_name;

Outputs:



AB




[1,2]


[3,4]


[5,6]



Creating an array from the column values within each row.
And:
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(a) AS all_a, JSON_ARRAYAGG(b) AS all_b FROM table_name;

Outputs:



ALL_A
ALL_B




[1,3,5]
[2,6,4]



Aggregating values across the rows.

Neither is "better" to use as they do different things. When you want to combine values within a row use JSON_ARRAY and when you want to aggregate values across rows use JSON_ARRAYAGG. Use the correct one for your task at hand.
fiddle
